# How to access the response from a AWSCustomResource?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am using custom resource to make a `getObject` call on an S3 bucket in `stack-1`.

Is it possible to use the response of this API call in another stack `stack-2` ?

```
const customResource = new AwsCustomResource(this, 'CustomResource', <AwsCustomResourceProps>{
                onCreate: {
                    service: 'S3',
                    action: 'getObject',
                    parameters: {
                        Bucket: 'bucket_name',
                        Key: `key`
                    },
                    physicalResourceId: PhysicalResourceId.of(`CustomResource-${Date.now().toString()}`) // Always update physical ID so function gets executed
                },
                role: Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'S3CrossAccountAccessRole', 'ROLE_ARN'),
                installLatestAwsSdk: false,
                logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK
});

console.log(customResource.getResponseField('Data.Body');
```

The CustomResource is created successfully. The lambda used by the CustomResource actually returns the field `Data.Body` in the response.

Logging the response doesn't print any value.

Comment: Your CDK code just generates the cloudoformation template, it runs locally and you cannot inspect the actual values before you deploy the template, so your `console.log` will print a Token reference. When you pass it to other CDK constructs, the token will be resolved to its actual value during deployment.

Comment: Is it possible to export this value and modify in the CDK code ? I will be making more than 1 API calls.

Comment: No, this code runs during deployment, not during the generation of the template. Use another lambda-backed custom resource to modify it.

Comment: By "this code" I mean the API call to AWS.

Comment: @gshpychka How can I access a config file during build time and read its values in cdk code ?

Comment: Have the config file be part of the git repo, ideally.

Comment: @gshpychka I have a dynamic json file which gets updated every day and lives in a S3 bucket which I am trying to retrieve in the above code. Is it possible to read this file before synth for me to use it to build my stack ?